# SSRS - Using ReportServer AddEvent, not processing subscriptions always

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I'm trying to create a homegrown subscription system for our ReportServer for QA purposes. I'm creating subscriptions on the front end and setting them on a schedule to execute once in the past (1/1/2019 for example) so the only way they would be executed is manually.

I looked at the jobs and they are simply executing a procedure "ReportServer.dbo.AddEvent" with EventType and EventData as parameters. When I execute that procedure, it adds a record to the Event table and then the Notifications table for the RS to pick up and process the subscription. Most of the time it works but sometimes it just hangs. I'm finding this for data-driven subscriptions especially. They are stuck in pending/processing and never execute fully.

Has anyone else had issues with this before? I'm building out a homegrown system because we have 200+ reports that we want to execute on a nightly basis. They are usually pretty quick but I want to only execute a handful at a time and I'm taking care of this through a custom Queue table.

Comment: Also I'm seeing the record(s) being removed from the Event table but not from the Notifications table.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out within the log files... It was data-driven but each version had the same file name and it was trying to overwrite a file that was still open.